# SparkSQL fails to read a specific column from an ORC table in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, orc

I am using `SparkSQL 2.1.1` to read from an ORC table in `Hive 1.2.1` stored in Google Cloud Storage. I can successfully select most of the columns except for one (called here `col1`) of type `smallint`. If I try to select that specific column with this code

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val result = hc.sql("SELECT col1 FROM table")
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

It will fails with this Exception:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 24.0 (TID 378, , executor 42): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable cannot
>   be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.ShortWritable
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableShortObjectInspector.get(WritableShortObjectInspector.java:36)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(TableReader.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(TableReader.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:435)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:426)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:232)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I have already tried to cast that column to type `short` without success

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val result = hc.sql("SELECT cast(col1 as short) FROM table")
result.collect().foreach(println)
```